# jQuery Scroll Function based on multiple event

Tags: javascript, jquery

let say I have some `div` with the structure like this

```
<main>
   <header id="foo"></header>
   <article id="bar"></bar>
   <div id="someDiv"></div>
   <div id="stickyDiv"></div>
   <footer id="bikiniBottom"></footer>
```

the `stickyDiv` is the element that stick in the bottom of the page. it only appears if user scroll down the page using javascript, and dissapear when user scroll to top

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
        window.onscroll = function() {
        var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
        if (prevScrollpos < currentScrollPos) {
            document.getElementById("stickyDiv").style.bottom = "0";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("stickyDiv").style.bottom = "-80px";
        }
        prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
        }
```

In this case I want to ask how to make earlier script only working when reached the `bar` element then dissapear again before reach the footer

thank you

Comment: can you please attach Jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by reach the bar element. I am assuming that you mean that when bar reaches the top, show the footer and hide the footer then bar goes out of view. I have included a range, since sometimes scroll position might be missed if user scrolls fast. Feel free to adjust according to your needs

You could do something like,

```
var $el = $('#bar');
var top = $el.position().top;
var bottom = top + $el.height();
if(Math.abs(top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 5) {    
   console.log('Bar is at the top');
   document.getElementById("stickyDiv").style.bottom = "0";
} 

if(Math.abs(bottom - $(window).scrollTop()) < 5) {
   console.log('Bar went out of view');
  document.getElementById("stickyDiv").style.bottom = "-80px";
}
```

Comment: pardon me, not sure if put the code properly but the code seems not working

Comment: Use the code above as a reference to get what you want. Difficult to test code with having a JSfiddle in place